# Nginx Restart Error: emerg duplicate upstream

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I have just installed an ssl certfificate on my server. It worked... for about an hour. Now the site isn't loading. When I go do nginx -t I am getting this error:

```
nginx: [emerg] duplicate upstream "app_server" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/rails.save:1
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Thiis is what  is in my rails.save file:

```
upstream app_server {
    server unix:/var/run/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://www.exammple.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    rewrite   ^(.*)  https://www.example.com$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen   443 ssl;
    root /home/rails/example/public;
    server_name www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate /example.com.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /example.com.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:!aNULL;
    index index.htm index.html;

    location / {
            try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|mp3|f$
                    try_files $uri @app;
            }

     location @app {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }
}
```

Here is my nginx.conf file

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        client_max_body_size 150M;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml applicat$

        ##
        # nginx-naxsi config
        ##
        # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
        ##

        #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

##
        # nginx-passenger config
        ##
        # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
        ##

        #passenger_root /usr;
        #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
```

Comment: I am allowed to do nginx restart but now when I go to the site I'm getting a 504 Gateway Time-out

Comment: Did you make sure that the socket is working correctly? If so, please show a debug log of a request which fails.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still new at all this server stuff so I don't really know what you're talking about. How do you check the socket?

Comment: I just checked the error log and it's saying: `invalid URL prefix in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/rails.save:40`

Comment: Could you use `proxy_pass http://unix:/var/run/unicorn.sock;` and see if this works?

Comment: Thank you for the help. I substituted that in for my original proxy_pass but I'm still getting the 504 error. The error code in the log file is now: `16/01/02 12:09:19 [error] 27451#0: *3 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream`

Comment: If you're using only one backend server, you don't need `upstream`, just use `proxy_pass` on it's own. Regarding the error: Well, you've to debug. As I said, helpful would be a debug error log, because this might show more information.

Comment: Hang on... it started working! Thank you so much (I replaced the proxy pass with the what you wrote above (`proxy_pass http://unix:/var/run/unicorn.sock;`) and it started working after a few minutes). Thank you so much for the help : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helpful steps taken, according to the comments:

- Removed `upstream` config directive.
- Replaced `proxy_pass http://app_server;` with 
  `proxy_pass http://unix:/var/run/unicorn.sock;`.